# How to configure a netty pipeline for a http proxy

Tags: java, http, netty, http-proxy

I wrote a small http proxy using Netty and it has worked fine for some time now. Today I began getting strange exceptions in the log file coming from a single client:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported message type: DefaultFullHttpResponse (expected: ByteBuf, FileRegion)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.filterOutboundMessage(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:276) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:654) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1054) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:651) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.write(LoggingHandler.java:289) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:706) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:131) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:54) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:283) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

Looking up the source code it seems the problem occurs when sending a `100 Continue` status in response to a `POST` request (`HttpObjectAggregator` lines 130-139)

```
if (is100ContinueExpected(m)) {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(CONTINUE).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) 
                throws Exception {
            if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                ctx.fireExceptionCaught(future.cause());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and indeed the client causing the issue seems to be the only one sending an `Expect: 100-continue` header along with the request. This makes me think my handler pipeline could be setup wrong:

```
p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG));
p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH));
p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
p.addLast(new MyHandler(...));
```

The API docs for `HttpObjectAggregator` state that

> Be aware that you need to have the HttpResponseEncoder or HttpRequestEncoder before the HttpObjectAggregator in the ChannelPipeline.

So I'm thinking both the `HttpRequestDecoder` and `HttpResponseEncoder` should precede `HttpObjectAggregator` in the pipeline. Could that be my problem?

Comment: Did you try changing the order (Aggregator being the last one before your MyHandler)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try changing the order (Aggregator being the last one before your MyHandler)?